# Java XML from URL

Tags: java, xml

Please find me where i wrong.
When i try parse xml file from URL, i get only root element, but node list  is empty

```
NodeList nodeListClients = documentClients.getElementsByTagName("clientsDTO");
```

If i reading same xml  from file then all right.
I dont't understand what is difference,file's content is the same.

```
public static Document loadTestDocument(HttpsURLConnection connection) throws Exception {
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8");
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(reader);
        inputSource.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
       // printDocument(factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputSource));
        return factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputSource);
    }



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<queryResponse count="1227" first="0" last="999" requestUrl="https:///webacs/api/v1/data/Clients?deviceName=startsWith(&quot;h&quot;)&amp;.maxResults=1000&amp;.full=true" responseType="listEntityInstances" rootUrl="https://prime.tpu.ru/webacs/api/v1/data" type="Clients">
<entity dtoType="clientsDTO" type="Clients" url="https://webacs/api/v1/data/Clients/5073819">
    <clientsDTO displayName="5073819" id="5073819">
        <associationTime>1500973785745</associationTime>
        <clientInterface>FastEthernet0/10</clientInterface>
        <connectionType>WIRED</connectionType>
        <deviceIpAddress>10.2.59.7</deviceIpAddress>
        <deviceName>h17-7-asw.cc.tpu.ru</deviceName>
        <deviceType>Unknown</deviceType>
        <ipAddress>NULL_VALUE</ipAddress>
        <location>Unknown</location>
        <macAddress>70:5a:b6:71:78:08</macAddress>
        <protocol>DOT3</protocol>
        <securityPolicyStatus>PASSED</securityPolicyStatus>
        <status>ASSOCIATED</status>
        <updateTime>1500973793656</updateTime>
        <vendor>Compal</vendor>
        <vlan>VLAN0871</vlan>
        <vlanId>871</vlanId>
    </clientsDTO>
</entity>

public static Document loadTestDocumentFile(String filePath) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
   // printDocument(factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(filePath));
    return factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Post the XML; it doesn't make much sense to ask why your XML is not parsed correctly without showing it.

Comment: I think I found a solution
NodeList nodeListClients = documentClients.getElementsByTagName ("entity");

Comment: Incorrect XML: it has to have a single root element, but yours have two: `queryResponse` and `entity`... or just left out the closing element of one of them...

Comment: but i don't understand ? why it's worked when i read xml from file  and dont'wor when i read from url.

Comment: How did you read from local file?

Comment: Added the above method loadTestDocumentFile